# ASP.NET Core 3.1 + CORS + Windows Authentication = 401 Unauthorized

Tags: cors, authorization, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1, iis-10

I have configured the [IIS CORS Module](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module) in my .NET Core 3.1(.201) web API hosted on IIS 10 and now I get `401 Unauthorized` on GET (not OPTIONS) requests for Windows authenticated users, **with or withoud** the `[Authorize]` attribute at controller or action level. Swagger instead goes through, returning 200 on the same action, so I'm thinking the authorization works, therefore the issue must be related to CORS somehow.

I've seen some workarounds enabling anonymous authentication and setting some authorization filters in `Startup.cs` but I'd like to stick with the IIS CORS Module since it was designed to properly cover this scenario, among others.

So maybe someone can help me figure out what am I doing wrong.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">
        <add origin="http://localhost:4300" allowCredentials="true">
          <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
            <add header="credentials" />
          </allowHeaders>
        </add>
      </cors>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProj.Api.exe" hostingModel="InProcess" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

...

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => ...
```

The javascript request (which uses `fetch API`) sets the `credentials: include` header.

I also tried [the approach suggested by Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Nov/14/FireFox-Windows-Security-and-Kestrel-on-ASPNET-Core) on his great web log but I got the same result: 401

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding CORS in the Startup class?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    ...
}
```

And in the Configure method:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: Yes, that's how it is currently implemented, but without authorization. And from what I understand, the authorization of Windows authenticated users cannot be set up with CORS configured in the middleware. 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17602#issuecomment-562105314

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the iis to handle the cors request. set below code in web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <!-- <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> -->
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

https://medium.com/@lukelindner/windows-authentication-with-net-core-api-and-angular-project-on-iis-ae16a573902e

https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module